# Mongo Import using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I am new to MEAN Stack and I have a task where I need to import a JSON survey file to MongoDB. I am using ng-file-upload library on the client side. How can I import the JSON file directly to MongoDB using Mongoose ODM? And what should be the request on Express JS route?